# Categorizing Layers in ArcGIS Pro Like QGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, classification

Is there a way in ArcGIS Pro to easily and quickly categorize, display, and hide layers as there is in QGIS (example in image)? This feature in QGIS makes it easy to work with layers that have the same geometry, and I haven't been able to find a way to quickly do this in Arc Pro.

Is there is a way, like in QGIS, to quickly display/hide layers with the check box? For example, I want to look at "11" and "13" so I would mark the box beside them. If I wanted to, I can quickly hide them by unchecking and then checking a new layer like "A1".

[image: QGIS Categorization]

Comment: in ArcGIS Pro it is under symbology >unique-values.>> https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/unique-value.htm

Comment: Thanks. I think what I'm really asking is if there is a way, like in QGIS, to quickly display/hide layers with the check box. For example, I want to look at "11" and "13" so I would mark the box beside them. If I wanted to, I can quickly hide them by unchecking and then checking a new layer like "A1".

Comment: IMO it is not possible in ArcGIS Pro